Navisworks Timeliner to Blender
I have a Navisworks project about the transformation of a Railway station.

The purpose is Coordination, clash detetection, 4D BIM planning.
There are too many limitations on the Navisworks Software, so I would like to test Blender.
I understand " a Timeliner" is no standard feature in Blender, but it can be coded.
I guess somebody did this before, if so, is this documented, can I take a look?

Hi, welcome to BSE! Blender being a 3D software aimed at creating movies/video-games assets and not engineering, and BSE being exclusively about Blender, using vocabulary from other software or industries is more likely to reduce the amount of readers that can understand you. I'd advise you to detail precisely what you are looking for in plain words that prerequires as little knowledge as possible, so that more people are able to help you.

Bonjour Lauloque,
a planning file provides a number of tasks.....between 1000 & 2000, which go with a tasks type (demolish-construct) and a code to match them with the model (4DSBS)
Then in the model you can import the complete task Hierarchy, and match the varoius elements with there 4DSBS code.
As this elements have various sources with a different parameter-structure, I have up to 5  "scenarios" to match them.
This allows me to run iterations in the planning of 1000 steps on a model of 20.000 elements very easily.

Hello, I suggest you look up Bonsai BIM, it's an extension for Blender focused on BIM capabilites, among them 4D planning even though it's not feature complete it may be of help. Also check out https://community.osarch.org/

Was about to recommend the same, Bonsai BIM may be able to do some of those things, https://community.osarch.org/discussion/1701/blenderbim-4d-crash-course If it can't yet and you are willing to role up your sleeves, maybe you can contribute your improvements
